# Distinct-Nodes taking too long in BaseX (XQuery)

Tags: xquery, basex

I am trying to get all distinct start element `/products/p:category/start` nodes of a big file. I have written a query which is given below. It is taking to long to get the result. I am attaching the query info and the XML file.

After Running couple of minutes, I stopped the execution.

The query is trying to get all the distinct start elements. There are 3 lac category elements.

```
declare namespace functx = "http://www.functx.com";
declare namespace p="a:b:c";

declare function functx:is-node-in-sequence( 
  $node as node()? , 
  $seq as node()* 
)  as xs:boolean {
  some $nodeInSeq in $seq satisfies deep-equal($nodeInSeq,$node)
};

declare function functx:distinct-nodes( 
  $nodes as node()*
) as node()* {
  for $seq in (1 to count($nodes))
  return $nodes[$seq]
         [not(functx:is-node-in-sequence(.,$nodes[position() < $seq]))]} ;

let $diff_starts := functx:distinct-nodes(/products/p:category/start)
return $diff_starts
```

Please let me know if you require further details.

[xml file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_pB7l14skhVLWxvZGNyMnFwc0k/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2):

Comparing a rather large number of nodes with the function provided by FunctX is *very* expensive, and far beyond costs linear with the number of items.

FunctX is generally a neat library, but often does not scale very well for larger data as you have it (although XML databases can very well handle data much larger without problems).

In this query, I first fetch all distinct values in linear time (in the number of node lookups; for getting distinct values [BaseX uses a hashtable](https://github.com/BaseXdb/basex/blob/master/basex-core/src/main/java/org/basex/query/func/fn/FnDistinctValues.java#L27) ), and another linear scan over all nodes to retrieve the first result node for each of those values. Total execution time on my laptop was about 700ms.

```
declare namespace p="a:b:c";
for $date in distinct-values(/products/p:category/start)
return (/products/p:category/start[. eq $date])[1]
```